# what is difference between where and find in laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

when I write this `$thread = Thread::find($id);` then I write `{{$thread->title}}` it gives me the title of the thread, but when I write `$thread = Thread::where('id','=',$id);` then I write `{{$thread->title}}` it gives me an error.why is that happening?

Comment: `where` (with a `get()` to actually execute the statement) returns a result set, which can be none, one or many records as an iterable collection of Thread models; `find` returns a single record as an instance of the Thread model

Comment: Have you tried reading the manual?

Answer (score 1):

You should write:

```
$thread = Thread::where('id','=',$id)->first();
```

to get one column, else laravel will understand it as array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the get() (or any of its variants) method to execute the actual query when using where.

```
   Thread::where('id','=',$id)->get();
```

Otherwise `Thread::where('id','=',$id)` just gets you an instance of eloquent's query builder.

`find()` on the other hand will automatically run a query for whatever it is you want to find by you can't do all sorts of useful stuff (e.g. orderBy, paginate, etc.) that you can very easily pull of using the query builder.